# h:outputscript source file not loaded in firefox

Tags: javascript, jsf, firefox

I have a facelet page which consists of

`<h:outputScript name="xyz.js" target="head"/>`

in the template.xhtml which loads the javascript data. The strange thing is the function from the "xyz.js" file are executed well in IE and chrome and cannot be executed in firefox.

The firefox is not able to find/load the javascript file.

Kindly help,

Comment: Logically, the generated HTML output, the HTTP traffic status and the JS error console should give clues as to the cause. Unfortunately, you didn't tell anything about them in your question. Press F12 in your webbrowser, observe them and edit your question to include the necessary detail.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for looking, The script with variable and functions are present in the html output according to firebug, but it says the variable is not defined when accessing them.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC again, Its working now, just replaced the jQuery form submit with the 'document.getElementById('newForm').submit()'